# How to change the background color of a single page in ionic 3+

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

[image]I am new to ionic and i have been trying to change a single page css like changing the background color to be something else. like green or so. i am aware i can change the same globally and i don't want to change the background  color globally i want it to be only on this single page.

I have tried the below but it seems not working.

I have tried searching but i am not finding anything fitting my need

**//page source code**

```
<ion-content class="contents">
     sample text goes here 
</ion-content>
```

```css
.contents{
  background-color:red;
}
ion-content{
  --background-color: var(--ion-color-danger, #f1453d);
}
```

the background should give me a red color for that page but it's not effecting the change

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem and tried ALL solutions mentioned here, and finally solved it by this:

```
<ion-content style="--background: #f1453d;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.contents {
  background: #f1453d;
}
```

Comment: still not working for me @Hecham.... i have tried background-color: #f1453d !important;is there anything i am missing pls

Comment: @Nazehs this is working in my project. can you reproduce issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-9rmjck?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: @sudarshana, i just discover that there is a CSS that is disabling my CSS and i have update my post with a snippet of my console. if i disabled that it will apply my css but the problem now is where to locate that css on my application to make the necessary changes

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this code on page.scss

```
ion-content {background: #f1453d !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In ionic v6 Beta1 this worked for me:

```
ion-content {
  --ion-background-color: red;
}
```